# Google App Engine firewall and internal access and error 403

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall, app-engine-flexible

We have 2 app engine app (flex and standard) running on separate projects and we want project A to request project B with https to `xxx.appspot.com` URL.

Our firewall on both projects Denies all IPs(*) and whitelisted App Engine internal addresss (10.1.0.41, 0.1.0.40, 10.0.0.1 and 0.1.0.30) as explained in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/creating-firewalls#allowing_requests_from_your_services).

Yet we receive a "403 error forbidden access" (which disappears when disabling the firewall).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685512/google-app-engine-firewall-and-internal-access) is similar to mine but the responses didn't help me.

Is there anything else I can do ?
Did anyone got this to work ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, GCP Projects represent a trust boundary within an organization. Hence, inter-project communication between App Engine services would require Public IP communication or using [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), which allows connecting between networks from different projects. There should be no internal communication between App Engine Services over different projects. Hence, whitelisting App Engine internal IP addresses might not be useful in this situation.

About using Public App Engine IP addresses, as illustrated in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#private-ip). App Engine hosts services on a dynamic public IP address of a Google load balancer. Due to that, the IP address can be changed any time and any Static IP can not be provided.  For outbound services, a large pool of IP addresses are used which you can obtain as outlined in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip)